# Output path being ignored when I build solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, project

I created separate configuration for my C# project. In project settings, for new configuration, I defined different output path (so for Debug I have bin\, for new configuration I have bin\NewConfig).

When I build my project under new configuration nothing appears in bin\NewConfig and from build log I can see that it removes files from bin\ and moves all files here.

How I can make my build files to appear in directory that I define in Output path? Could that setting be overridden or disabled somewhere else?

Comment: Did you switch the configuration of the solution or only of the project...,  You have to set the correct configuration for every project in the solution for the configuration of the solution.  (probably still points to default configuration of the project...)

Comment: @Schwarzie2478 thanks, you pointed me to the right direction. It turned out that in Configuration Manager, for new solution configuration, my project configuration was set to Debug. If you want to format your response as a proper answer I will accept it.

Comment: okidoki :-) will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remember that you are building a solution configuration for which you can choose which configuration of your projects are being built.

Check if the correct configuration of your project is selected for the selected solution configuration...